# Spring @Cacheable double-checked locking (infinispan backend)

Tags: java, spring, caching, infinispan

I recently started using Spring's `@Cacheable` annotation in an application to cache the result of some expensive operations. The code I want to replace is making extensive use of the double-checked locking pattern to ensure consistency of the cache and execution of the expensive routines only once like this:

```
final String key = SomeClass.computeKey(input)
String cachedValue = mCache.get(key);
if (cachedValue == null) {
    synchronized (mCache) {
        cachedValue = mCache.get(key);
        if (cachedValue == null) {
            cachedValue = expensiveComputing(input);  // must not be executed twice
            mCache.put(key, cachedValue);
        }
    }
}
```

The above was replaced by:

```
@Cacheable(value="someCache", key="T(SomeClass).computeKey(#input)")
public String expensiveComputing(Object input) {
    // must not be executed twice
}
```

Sometimes there is a second cache in place to cache the lock-object for the actual lookup to avoid extensive synchronization on the whole cache during computation of the cache value.

I already read [infinispan's docu on locking](http://infinispan.org/docs/stable/user_guide/user_guide.html#locking_and_concurrency) and am still wondering whether I need to take care of these aspects myself or if infinispan guarantees for the expected behavior.

According to the docu infinispan creates a new lock for each cache entry by default since 5.0 (I'm using 8.2.6). That is the 2 level caching of lock-object and cache value should be unnecessary, If I got this correctly?! But what about the double-checked locking pattern? Can this be removed as well? And will the `expensiveComputing` routine still be called only once in a heavily concurrent environment?

Comment: Those `synchronized` sections should not be needed. Infinispan Cache contains put if absent or compare-and-swap like operations that provide the guarantees you require. To be more precise, the code above could be replaced with just a `mCache.putIfAbsent`. I'm no expert, but I don't know what the equivalent with Spring @Cacheable annotations would be. One of my colleagues might be able to help.

Comment: That's the correct approach for this. Please use `putIfAbsent`.

Comment: @GalderZamarreño, @altanis, not exactly. I'd need a synchronized `computeIfAbsent` which the mentioned `sync` flag promises to provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer**

This is supported with Spring 4.3+ and Infinispan 9.0+ with `sync=true` in `@Cacheable` (see [this Spring ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9254) and [this Infinispan ticket](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN-7224))

**Long answer**

Pre-Spring 4.3, simply annotating the method with `@Cacheable` will not synchronize the code itself. All it does is wrap the methods into a proxy (see `o.s.c.a.JCacheCacheAspect` and `o.s.c.j.i.JCacheAspectSupport` for details) which doesn't include any additional synchronization when it tries to get the value from cache before invoking the method body.

So it's entirely possible for the expensive computation to occur twice. The additional synchronization is up to the programmer in this case. So the double-checked locking is still useful.

There is another option: as Infinispan provides its caching library as a JCache (JSR-107) provider, you may consider, instead of using the default `org.infinispan.jcache.annotation.InjectedCacheResultInterceptor`, writing your own implementation of `org.infinispan.jcache.annotation.AbstractCacheResultInterceptor`, which will take care of the locking. For example, your implementation of the class may have some dictionary to decide what kinds of `InvocationContext` require such locking.

Actually, it looks like using `@Cacheable` in this case brings more pain than gain. Creating a cache from transaction manager and using it to have some control over transactions like they do in Infinispan [tutorials](http://infinispan.org/docs/stable/getting_started/getting_started.html#transactional_cache_operations) seems to be easier and more concise.

Since Spring 4.3, `@Cacheable` has a [sync](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Cacheable.html) attribute which hints that the whole operation must be synchronized. Infinispan supports this since version 9.0.

Comment: Unfortunately [ISPN-7224](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN-7224) has been reopened just minutes ago. Thus the fix in 9.0 doesn't seem to be complete :-(

Comment: @dpr - It turned out that with Client/Server mode we need additional synchronization (which is currently implemented as lightweight client side locking). The embedded scenario should be fine though.

Comment: @altanis, thanks for the info. Unfortunately updating to infinispan 9.0 is currently not an option as we are using the async transfer option, which diminished in infinispan 9.